# Unable to login my AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

i was logging in AWS server (ubuntu@54.564.564.1) with my pem key. After, i created one user in ubuntu and opened "/etc/ssh/sshd_config". In this file I have added following text "allow user username". I did reload that file and logout. but i unable to login my server with newuser(username@54.564.56.1) and olduser (ubu..@54.564.564.1).

Comment: Done you did the damage already. By any chance you have another user for the server.

Comment: is it EBS volume ? if so, stop your instance, create a new instance, login, attach the EBS volume, mount it and fix your file, once the file is save, reattach the EBS volume to your previous ec2 instance and start it

Comment: thanks for reply. i did not stop my instance. i terminated instance EC2. I got information from other site. once we terminated instance we can not get back. so I created new instance. thank you dude.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh'ing without the ubuntu@. Just do the ip address because usually the first part implies the username.

Ex:

if I ssh into my raspberry pi and do: pi@192.168.1.12 then it just asks me for my password not my username and I login as the user pi.

Hope this helped

Comment: no dude. already i tried. ubuntu user provided by aws. i did ssh ubuntu@0.0.0.0. in the terminal. same error i got